# Images are not displaying in gridView inside public void call method

Tags: java, android, gridview, socket.io

I've created a `Fragment` that should display some emojis in my `GridView`, when I try to put the URLs statically outside the public void call method the images get displayed successfully however when I put the code inside this method, the images don't display, I'm doing this for testing as I'm going to make it dynamic, but this is just for testing.

So, appreciate your assistance to advise why the images are not appearing inside this method specifically.

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


ArrayList<EmojiModel> emojieModels = new ArrayList<>();;
ArrayList<String> imageId = new ArrayList<>();
View grid;
GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter2 imageAdapter2;

public BottomSheetFragment() {
    // Empty Constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gifts_layout_2, container, 
                                      false);
    gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view2);


    getEmojies();
    imageAdapter2 = new ImageAdapter2(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                                                                   imageId);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter2);

    return rootView;

 }

    public void getEmojies(){
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Communicator.getInstance().on("subscribe start", new 
            Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

                }
            });
        }
    });

    }

public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> emojieImages = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<String> emojieImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.emojieImages = emojieImages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return emojieImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return emojieImages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public class Holder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent) {

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) 
        grid.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(emojieImages.get(position))
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return grid;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your method `runOnUIThread` is asynchronous.
To make it work you should set the adapter after the images are loaded:

```
@Override
public void call(Object... args) {

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageId.add("https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-
     247932.jpeg");

     imageAdapter2 = new ImageAdapter2(getActivity(), imageId);
     gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter2);
}
```

Also note that you don't need to call `runOnUIThread` inside a Fragment, it is already running on that thread.

Comment: That method is being called? Try to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image access problems

https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-%20247932.jpeg

Can not access

Comment: its not an issue. Then how got images on outside the method. This s right link https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg

Comment: sorry,  show me R.layout.gifts_layout_2 and R.layout.smiles_items_layout

Comment: This should be in comment on queston

Comment: 1,Maybe layout problem, so need u show the layout filem,  2, You can debug the getView().

Comment: if it is a layout problem it wouldn't have appeared when I type the urls outside the method, this issue only occurs inside the method

Comment: Communicator.getInstance().on("subscribe start", new 
            Emitter.Listener()) is called  on ui thread ?